# How can I replace the user prompt which currently determines the variable's value with an input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code. As you can see by running it, immediately two prompts are initiated, before any CSS is loaded in. The goal is to eliminate the user prompts for collecting variable values and replace them with input boxes (text boxes), which the user can then input their information, click a button and have the rest of the code operate off the same variables. When I tried this myself I ran into some issues, but the main one which I would be interested in seeing how it is solved is that the rest of the javascript initiates before the user can input the information in the input boxes, which makes 
`CurrentTier` `CurrentBalance`and undefined.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fortnite Vbuck Calculator</title>
  <div id="Title"><img src="TitlePNGv2.png"></div>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
#Title {
  text-align:center;
}

#Declaration {
  font-family: "Quicksand";
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:white;
}

html {
  background-image: url("FORTNITEBACKGROUNDv2.png");
}
</style>
<script>
var CurrentTier = prompt("What is your current battlepass tier?");
var CurrentBalance = prompt("How many Vbucks do you currently have?");
var Remaining1To3 = 1500;
var Remaining4To9 = 1400;
var Remaining10To17 = 1300;
var Remaining18To18 = 1100
var Remaining19To25 = 1100;
var Remaining26To33 = 1000;
var Remaining34To34 = 900;
var Remaining35To41 = 800;
var Remaining42To50 = 700;
var Remaining51To57 = 600;
var Remaining58To63 = 500;
var Remaining64To73 = 400;
var Remaining74To82 = 300;
var Remaining83To89 = 200;
var Remaining90To97 = 100;
var Remaining98To100 = 0;

if (CurrentTier >= 1 && CurrentTier <= 3) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining1To3;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 4 && CurrentTier <= 9) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining4To9;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 10 && CurrentTier <= 17) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining10To17;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 18 && CurrentTier <= 18) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining18To18;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 19 && CurrentTier <= 25) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining19To25;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 26 && CurrentTier <= 33) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining26To33;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 34 && CurrentTier <= 34) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining34To34;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 35 && CurrentTier <= 41) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining35To41;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 42 && CurrentTier <= 50) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining42To50;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 51 && CurrentTier <= 57) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining51To57;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 58 && CurrentTier <= 63) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining58To63;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 64 && CurrentTier <= 73) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining64To73;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 74 && CurrentTier <= 82) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining74To82;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 83 && CurrentTier <= 89) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining83To89;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 90 && CurrentTier <= 97) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining90To97;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 98 && CurrentTier <= 100) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining98To100;
}

var FinalBalance = CurrentBalance*1+RemainingDeterminer

function myFunction() {
    var PrintedRemaining = FinalBalance;
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = PrintedRemaining;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div id="Declaration"><h1>If you finish the Battlepass, and do not spend any VBucks, you will have <span id="myText"></span> Vbucks.</h1></div><span id="myText"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So do you want to show the entered value in textbox?

Comment: No, I want the user to enter a value in the text box, have that value be assigned to the variable CurrentTier (I will copy paste for CurrentBalance), and then have those variables go through all the calculations in the code and be used normally. It’s really just the first step of collecting the user data for the variables that I want to change from the nasty prompt to a more user friendly input box.

Comment: where is textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it with some plain "Vanilla" JavaScript:

```js
function remaining(tier){
 var r,rmna=[[ 1, 1500],[ 4, 1400],[10, 1300],[18, 110],[19, 1100],
             [26, 1000],[34,  900],[35,  800],[42, 700],[51,  600],
             [58,  500],[64,  400],[74,  300],[83, 200],[90,  100],[98, 0]];
 rmna.forEach(rm=>{if (rm[0]>tier) return false; r=rm[1]});
 return r
}
function setCredits(o){
  var tier=document.getElementById("tier").value-0;
  var cred=document.getElementById("credit").value-0;
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML=cred+remaining(tier);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="tier" oninput="setCredits()"
   placeholder="Enter current tier here"> 
  <input type="text" id="credit" oninput="setCredits()"
   placeholder="Your current credits"> 
  <div id="Declaration">
  <h1>If you finish the Battlepass, and do not spend any VBucks,
      you will have <span id="myText"></span> Vbucks.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

The function `setCredits()` is bound to the input event of the newly introduced input field on top of your "Declaration" div. Actually, you can put this input field  anywhere you like on the page.

`setCredits()` will get the current value from both your input fields and will then transfer the calculated credit level (calculated within the function `remaining()`) to the target span with the id `myText`. (I removed the second span with the same Id from your HTML, since using the same id twice on a page would result in invalid markup.)

**A few more details:**
The function `remaining(tier)` replaces your lengthy section of multiple `if` statements and conditional assignments.

`document.getElementById("tier").value-0` will get the current input value from the input field with the id "tier" and will try to convert it into a numeric data type (by subtracting `0` from the returned text-type value)

Answer (score 0):

You could use php, in order to have php installed you must use something like XAMP or just an website host. There are pleanty of tutorials out there on how to install php on your website. I think you can better use php to process the data. Try adding something like this:

```
<?php
include 'action_page.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fortnite Vbuck Calculator</title>
  <div id="Title"><img src="TitlePNGv2.png"></div>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
#Title {
  text-align:center;
}

#Declaration {
  font-family: "Quicksand";
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:white;
}

html {
  background-image: url("FORTNITEBACKGROUNDv2.png");
}
</style>
<?php
  Echo "<form method='post' action='/action_page.php'>
  Battlepass tiers:<br>
  <input type='text' name='tiers'><br>
  Vbucks amount:<br>
  <input type='text' name='vbucks'>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>";
?>
<script>
var CurrentTier = <?php echo $tiers; ?>;  <!-- Here you get the variables from the 
                                          php -->
var CurrentBalance = <?php echo $vbucks; ?>;
var Remaining1To3 = 1500;
var Remaining4To9 = 1400;
var Remaining10To17 = 1300;
var Remaining18To18 = 1100
var Remaining19To25 = 1100;
var Remaining26To33 = 1000;
var Remaining34To34 = 900;
var Remaining35To41 = 800;
var Remaining42To50 = 700;
var Remaining51To57 = 600;
var Remaining58To63 = 500;
var Remaining64To73 = 400;
var Remaining74To82 = 300;
var Remaining83To89 = 200;
var Remaining90To97 = 100;
var Remaining98To100 = 0;

if (CurrentTier >= 1 && CurrentTier <= 3) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining1To3;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 4 && CurrentTier <= 9) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining4To9;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 10 && CurrentTier <= 17) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining10To17;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 18 && CurrentTier <= 18) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining18To18;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 19 && CurrentTier <= 25) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining19To25;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 26 && CurrentTier <= 33) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining26To33;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 34 && CurrentTier <= 34) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining34To34;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 35 && CurrentTier <= 41) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining35To41;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 42 && CurrentTier <= 50) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining42To50;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 51 && CurrentTier <= 57) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining51To57;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 58 && CurrentTier <= 63) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining58To63;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 64 && CurrentTier <= 73) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining64To73;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 74 && CurrentTier <= 82) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining74To82;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 83 && CurrentTier <= 89) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining83To89;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 90 && CurrentTier <= 97) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining90To97;
}

if (CurrentTier >= 98 && CurrentTier <= 100) {
  var RemainingDeterminer = Remaining98To100;
}

var FinalBalance = CurrentBalance*1+RemainingDeterminer

function myFunction() {
    var PrintedRemaining = FinalBalance;
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = PrintedRemaining;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div id="Declaration"><h1>If you finish the Battlepass, and do not spend any VBucks, you 
will have <span id="myText"></span> Vbucks.</h1></div><span id="myText"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

In the action page you will have to use this:

```
<?php

function calculate(){
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $tiers = $_POST['tiers']; /* This assigns the data from the form to the 
                                  variables */
        $vbucks = $_POST['vbucks'];
    }
}
```

So you make two files: one is the html page which you have to save as php! And a php script which I called 'action_page.php'. I havn't tested it out but I will later.